# Questionable practice of MO moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators, migration

A [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776280/polynomial-of-matrix) was recently migrated from MO to MSE. While it is crystal clear that MO is not the suitable place to post that question, at least two MO users had answered the question in their comments ***before*** the migration. Now, just what do the MO moderators expect us to do? To summarise the aforementioned comments into a community wiki answer? When did MSE users become subordinate clerks of MO moderators?

I don't object to migrations of questions in principle, but as I see it, MO is externalising the cost of routine clerk job to MSE in this case.

Comment: You're asssuming bad intent on part of the moderators here, while there are many other possible interpretations of the event. For example, if they acted from the flag queue they wouldn't have seen the comments by default.

Comment: If the question is off-topic on MO, isn't the alternate that the question is simply closed there and forgotten? (Or auto-deleted, depending on the votes?)

Comment: @MadScientist Nowhere in my post have I suggested that the moderators of MO had any bad intent. What I am suggesting is that by migrating the mentioned question, they are *in effect*, making troubles for us. The most natural answers to that question are already in the comments. We have a consensus that putting answers in the comments is not a good thing to do, haven't we?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that it was MO moderators who migrated the question? One of the alternatives presented to people voting to close a question on MO is to vote in favor of migrating the question to m.se, and if that option gets enough votes, then the question gets migrated, without (so far as I know) any activity on the part of any moderator.

Comment: @Gerry: Just checked the history: it was closed as off-topic, then 5 hours later, a moderator moved it over here. (after reopening it and then reclosing it)

Comment: Moreover, here is the kind of thing that can happen: 4 MO voters vote to migrate to m.se; then one or more MO people answer in the comments; then a 5th MO voter votes to close (and not necessarily to migrate). In that situation, I believe the question gets migrated; none of the pro-migration voters saw any comments; the only voter who saw comments didn't vote to migrate.

Comment: @Hurkyl, thanks, I hadn't figured out that I could see the history by appropriate clicking. It does seem like an odd thing for the moderator to do, if the voters didn't vote for migration, but I suppose he thought he was doing the author a favor.

Comment: Lastly: why exactly is this posted on _our_ meta? Wouldn't a better place to raise complaints about the behaviour of MO mods on the MathOverflow meta?

Answer (score 18):

I really don't understand the objection.

The post of interest belongs on MSE and got moved to MSE. Aside from that minor detail, there is no functional difference between this post and any of the myriad of other posts that get answered in the comments.

And to the best of my knowledge, it has never been the job of the moderators on any stackexchange site to post answers when there are answers in comments; your objection making it sound like you think the MO moderators are trying to make us do their job for them.

Comment: The initial states are different! Every question that is first posted on MSE carries no comments (and hence no answers in the comments), but MO is now dumping a question that is already answered in the comments.

Comment: @user, so what?

Comment: How in the world is it worse for a question to have answers in the comments than no answers at all?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber on that note, some reasons that one might consider answering in a comment to be a bad thing include: answers given in comments can't be downvoted if they are wrong, can't be edited to fix errors or clarify (except in special cases), can easily get buried in "fluff" comments, and can make actual answers less visible (if actual answers are posted later). Plus comments are meant to be temporary.